# Which should i use Handler or Thread?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I'm trying to develop simple audio player and i found that handler and thread do the same function for Seekbar moveing:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Start();
        update();
    }

    private void update() {
        sk.setProgress(mp.getCurrentPosition());

        //hand.postDelayed(MainActivity.this,100);
        //new Thread(MainActivity.this).start();

    }


    @Override
    public void run() {
        update();
    }
```

***Note i implement `Runnable` to MainActivity.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handler and Thread do NOT do the same thing.

A Handler processes a Runnable, either now or in the near future (if you use postDelayed).  It does this on the Thread that it was created on.

A Thread is a separate line of execution-  its a series of instructions that happen at the same time as other Threads.  A thread is how you get two things to happen on a computer at the same time.

While both take a Runnable as a parameter, they do totally different things.  Which one is appropriate for you?  If you want to do something in N seconds on the UI thread, like updating the UI, use a Handler.  If you want to do extensive background processing or network requests, use a Thread.